# Searching Keywords in a text file in Java

Tags: java

I have a text file Im reading in and i need to only read keywords in this file and what the value of that keyword equals for example, buffer = 20, any ideas where to start researching?

Comment: Where is the value stored?

Comment: Well http://lucene.apache.org/

Comment: `regex`, `filereader`, `fileinputstream`, `String.split()`- should be enough. If this is a "Property-like" file, you could probably use the java `Properties` to open that file as a properties file, and read the keys and associated values. As @Vwin said, you didn't tell us where the values are stored.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following solution that you can use:

1. Because I have no idea what is your source file, I have used the
   current source html page and saved as "targetFile.html".
2. I have created a simple class TestScanner that will look into
   targetFile.html for all occurrences of "buffer = xxx".

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    /**
     * 
     * @author Franklin Neves
     *
     */
    public class TestScanner {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                try {
                    // Get the current path
                    String currentPath = TestScanner.class.getProtectionDomain()
                            .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();

                    // Convert file to String
                    String fileContent = new Scanner(new File(currentPath
                            + "targetFile.html")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

                    // Create pattern to filter the desired "buffer = XXX"
                    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("buffer = \\d*",
                            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

                    // Apply pattern to the content
                    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(fileContent);

                    // Loop to all occurrences
                    while (mat.find()) {
                        // Print each occurrence
                        System.out.println(mat.group());
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Hopefully you find this useful.

Best Regards, Franklin Neves